# Appium session running on same device in parallel execution

Tags: java, testng, appium, appium-android

I am trying to run two different test cases parallelly on two different devices. I am doing following steps to run the test cases :

1) Open two appium server instances using below commands

```
appium -p 4723 -bp 4724 --chromedriver-port 4725 -U "ZY3223QGDP"
appium -p 4726 -bp 4727 --chromedriver-port 4728 -U "ZY223XJFNS"
```

I have followed below appium guidelines for starting appium servers :
  https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/parallel-tests.md

2) I have created two testng classes to hold both test cases. Below is the code for both the classes and tetng xml file.

3) I am printing appium session in both test cases. For which different values are printed. Even appium logs suggest that both the appium driver are interacting to their respective servers.

In both test I am using different application, but only one test cases pass and one fail. In both test cases I take screenshot which give screenshot of same devices.

Test 1

```
package com.qklab.register;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.qk.automation.framework.AppiumManagerTestng;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

public class DeviceOneAppOne {

    @Test
    public void test1(HashMap<String,Object> testDetail) throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, String> deviceDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
        deviceDetails.put("app_activity","com.hdfc.retail.netbanking.HDFCBank");
        deviceDetails.put("app_package","com.snapwork.hdfc");
        deviceDetails.put("appium_port","4726");
        deviceDetails.put("appium_ip","0.0.0.0");
        deviceDetails.put("udid","ZY223XJFNS");
        deviceDetails.put("device_name","moto black");
        deviceDetails.put("platform_version","8.1.0");
        deviceDetails.put("platform_name","Android");

        AppiumManagerTestng appiumManager = new AppiumManagerTestng();
        AppiumDriver appiumDriver = appiumManager.getAppiumDriverForTestng(deviceDetails);

            try {

                System.out.println("got session id : " + appiumDriver.getSessionId());

                //Take screenshot
                File srcFile=appiumDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                File targetFile=new File("ZY223XJFNS" +".jpg");
                System.out.println(targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
                FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,targetFile);

                appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@*[contains(.,'SKIP INTRODUCTION')]]")).click();

            }catch(Exception ex) {
                throw ex;
            }       
    }

}
```

2) Test 2

```
package com.qklab.register;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.qk.automation.framework.AppiumManagerTestng;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;


public class DeviceTwoAppTwo {

    @Test
    public void test2(HashMap<String,Object> testDetail) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> deviceDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
        deviceDetails.put("app_activity","com.atomyes.MainActivity");
        deviceDetails.put("app_package","com.atomyes");
        deviceDetails.put("appium_port","4723");
        deviceDetails.put("appium_ip","0.0.0.0");
        deviceDetails.put("udid","ZY3223QGDP");
        deviceDetails.put("device_name","moto silver");
        deviceDetails.put("platform_version","7.0");
        deviceDetails.put("platform_name","Android");

        AppiumManagerTestng appiumManager = new AppiumManagerTestng();
        AppiumDriver appiumDriver = appiumManager.getAppiumDriverForTestng(deviceDetails);

        try {
            //Take screenshot
            File srcFile=appiumDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File targetFile=new File("ZY3223QGDP" +".jpg");
            FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,targetFile);

            appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Skip To Login']")).click();
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            throw ex;
        }

    }


}
```

3) AppiumDriver generator

```
package com.qk.automation.framework;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class AppiumManagerTestng {

    public AppiumDriver getAppiumDriverForTestng(HashMap<String, String> deviceDetails) throws Exception {
        AppiumDriver driverForTestng = null;
        String app_activity = deviceDetails.get("app_activity");
        String app_package = deviceDetails.get("app_package");
        String appium_port = deviceDetails.get("appium_port");
        String appium_ip = deviceDetails.get("appium_ip");
        String udid = deviceDetails.get("udid");
        String device_name = deviceDetails.get("device_name");
        String platform_version = deviceDetails.get("platform_version");
        String platform_name = deviceDetails.get("platform_name");
            try
            {
                DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
                dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, device_name);
                dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, platform_version);
                dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, platform_name);
                dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
                dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
                //dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
                dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
                dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, app_package);
                dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, app_activity);
                driverForTestng = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://" + appium_ip + ":" + appium_port + "/wd/hub"),dc);  
            }

            catch(Exception objDriverException){
                objDriverException.printStackTrace();

            }

        return driverForTestng;
    }

}
```

4) Testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
  <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.qklab.register.DeviceOneAppOne"> 
       <methods>
        <include name="test1" />
      </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
   <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.qklab.register.DeviceTwoAppTwo"> 
       <methods>
        <include name="test2" />
      </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Above code should run both test cases independently of each other. But this is not happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add more details about what is the error that you are seeing? Your code looks threadsafe and I dont see any evident problems in it.

Comment: Curious to know that are these class/tests running at all? Because the test method require one argument `HashMap<String,Object> testDetail` and it is not passed either as parameter or using data-provider. Regardless, While starting appium, instead of using `-U` which is deprecated, you can try `-dc` or `--default-capabilities`. For example: `--default-capabilities [ '{"app": "myapp.app", "deviceName": "iPhone Simulator"}' | /path/to/caps.json ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the deviceName & udid and use **avd** capability with your emulators name(both are different) e.g. cap.setCapability("avd", "moto_silver");.

- DeviceName will look like:  emulator-5554
- 'avd' name will look like: moto silver

This will launch two different devices and tests independently.